# Repaired MBR from WinXP, now Fedora won't boot

Tags: windows, linux, windows-xp, anti-virus

I have a machine on which I installed windows XP and then installed Fedora 18.
Everything worked fine when booted Fedora first time.

But when I booted XP my antivirus software prompted me with  a message for corrupted MBR and asked me to repair it.

I pressed `yes` and when I booted again, it directly boots XP.

Can anybody told how to use the XP bootmgr to display boot menu?
I have installed Fedora on different drive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall the grub bootloader. It can easily be done with a live disk. This [link](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) should help you. Also, please remove this antivirus garbage.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am looking forward to it. Can you please tell me how to configure winxp to show boot menu. that antivirus software is purchased one, agreed, but not possible for me

Comment: I disagree with removing the anti virus. Reading what it wants to do and googling on that if you do not understand what it ask would have helped though.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed windows XP it installed itself to one of the hard drives **and** set up a boot record on the first drive, pointing to it own start up sequence. This is normal.

Then you installed Fedora. It also needs a way to start up. There are at least two ways to choose between these:

1. Let it boot into the start up menu of Fedora (probably GRUB) where you can select Fedora or XP.
2. Let it boot into the start up menu of XP (bootmng), where you can select XP and probably also Fedora.

I think you installed the Fedora manager and it worked.  Then you booted into XP and it detected changes to the start up parts. Those were benign and without changing them everything would have worked. (Read: if you pressed 'no' all would be fine).

However some older style virusses also modify these things, which is the reason your anti virus cam with a warning. When you pressed 'yes' you wiped the changes which Fedora made.

You now have two choices:

1. Change the XP bootloader so it also recognises XP.
2. Boot Fedora again (from a CD or pen drive) and reinstall its bootloader.

To change the XP bootloaded, look for the file `boot.ini` on the C: drive and edit it so it resembles the contents below.

```
[boot loader]
timeout=20
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows XP" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\BOOTPART\fedora10.bin="Fedora 10"
```

Note that you will need to locate and copy the relevant fedora.bin part to your C drive. Since you already have the Fedora installation media that is just a question of copying the right files.

The other alternative it to reboot the Fedora installation, [reinstall or reconfigure GRUB](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) and press `no` when you boot back into windows. This might be as single as booting Fedora and running `grub2-install /dev/sda` again (which will reinstall itself into the MBR).

Comment: "Note that you will need to locate and copy the relevant fedora.bin ... that is just a question of copying the right files." - Umm, **no**. There is no ready-made fedora10.bin; it needs to be created by copying the Grub bootloader code from the MBR, using either dd or the *bootpart* program (which is why you see C:\BOOTPART mentioned). This (adding Linux to boot.ini) also requires Grub to be installed on the / (Linux root) partition instead of the MBR (which should contain NTLDR). Perhaps you should direct the OP to the [detailed source](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=228580).